# Can we make android icons non-clickable android?

Tags: android, launcher, clickable

I am trying to create a launcher application, in which I want some of the icons to be non-tappable. Is this possible in android ?

Comment: it means you don't want to perform any click event ?

Comment: Yes, I don't want the icon to clickable.

Comment: It will be you own launcher. And you must manage every click on it  and launch or not any app from your launcher.

Comment: @jimpanzer We will have the control of click on icons in our launcher ?